# Getting java.lang.IllegalAccessError when attempting to access Firestore collection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, apache-beam, java-11

I am getting the exception below when I try to call my Spring application from Apache Beam using direct runner.

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: 
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class 
io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor tried to access 
private field io.opencensus.trace.unsafe.ContextUtils.CONTEXT_SPAN_KEY 
(io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor and 
io.opencensus.trace.unsafe.ContextUtils are in unnamed module of loader 
java.net.URLClassLoader @72906e)
```

This line of code is there in a micro service. I created a jar and added that dependency in Apache Beam.

This is the line causing the error:

```
 ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> future = firestore.collection("dev-project-tablename")
                    .whereEqualTo("key", key).get();
```

From Apache Beam, I have instantiated the Firestore object using:

```
Firestore fireStore = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably having a different version of opencensus binaries as a transient dependency. If your project is maven based you can use maven dependency:tree to list all dependencies. You can also check this issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/310

To resolve it you have to bump the version of some of your firebase dependencies, no sure which since you haven't added these details.